# QGIS print composer atlas shortcut next feature

Tags: qgis, features, printing, print-composer, atlas

I have 25 features in the atlas of the print composer and I need to check every feature before exporting. It's quite annoying to always click the field in the status bar, so I wanted to use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> for showing the next feature. But it doesn't work since when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> it already starts zooming in the present feature.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Or better, is there a way to quickly show a certain feature, like a field where I can fill in 23 and then the composer shows me map 23?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. Eg, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press the <kbd>.</kbd> key.

QGIS master (and the future 2.12 release) has a combobox for jumping directly to a specific atlas page. But in QGIS < 2.12 you can still jump to a specific atlas page feature. Just open the attribute table for your coverage layer, right click the desired feature and select "Set as atlas feature for composer...".

Comment: That's it. It's a bit irritating that in the status bar the shortcut is explained as 'CTRL+.', I think the + is not needed there...
I still don't understand how to jump to a specific atals page feature (QGIS 2.10.1). When I open the attribute table of my coverage layer I can't right clicl features there. And within the print composer I don't have access to the attribute table, or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: If you want a specific feature, the easiest thing to do is create a filter in the atlas generation tab in the composer.